# Amd driver stopped responding and has recovered from an error

Tags: drivers, hardware-failure, gpu

So this is 3 weeks since I got the GPU Sapphire R9 270 2GB.

The other specs for my PC are:

- CPU: Amd FX 8320
- PSU: Corsair RM 750W
- RAM: 4GB DDR3 1366 (for now)
- SSD: Samsung 840 Evo
- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-97A-UD3P

**All new Except rams!**

Since I got the Graphics card I started getting AMD Driver has stopped and recovered from an error.

Sometimes I can play any game (Diablo 3, Dota 2, Metro LL, Battlefield 4) at ultra and it runs fine for hours .. but if I alt tab or something like that bam .. black screen 3-5 seconds .. I get the erorr and when I get back to game I hear sound but no video .. only way is to close game with task manager.

Now this happens even more frequently doing simple trivial tasks like while simply playing a video with flash player online screen freezes for seconds and I get the error or just small 1-sec spikes during the video.

In these 3 weeks I've tried everything I could with the information from forums, youtube etc. simply nothing.

I'm at the edge of desparation and sending it to warranty it's my last option since it will take a long time and leave me without a running PC.

**What I've tried :**

- windows fix-it
- the gpu memmory timer for freeze with regedit
- unplug-replug everything on the motherboard
- reinstalling drivers with driver cleaner(and some other driver cleaners from all previous gpu's I had)
- installing older versions of drivers
- bios optimised defaults
- modifying the driver file in system 32 folder(atikmdag.sys)
- delete Chrome gpu files and/or use other browser
- memory test
- bunch of other stuff I don't remember now ...
- format drive and reinstall windows !!

After all this as I said I'm pretty close to losing all hope .. the most likely scenario seems to be either Voltage problems(although the PSU ran fine for 3 weeks with another GPU and is a solid PSU as you can see) or a faulty broken GPU came from factory.

What else should/can I try. Please help me in any way you can think of I want to try everything before sending it back to warranty.

Comment: Try to contact AMD support before sending it, they might be able to help you more then as because they develop the drivers and they should already know about reports like this since it's their software.

Comment: Have you tried cataylst 14.6 the beta driver dated 5/27/2014?  Have you tried monitoring software to check the temperatures and voltages of your system?  For example: speedfan  Voltages, even under load should be + or - 5% max.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you've tried everything (and then some) that I'd usually suggest to a user in your situation. If possible, I would try replacing your 270 with a known working GPU (get one from a friend if you don't have an extra one) and seeing if it works. Also, did you run memtest?
Otherwise, if I was in your position, I would just send it to the manufacturer. Either survive for some time without a computer or get a cheap PCI-e replacement card. I find that's always something nice to have on hand if your motherboard does not have integrated graphics.

Comment: I used an HD 7850 with my curent configuration before getting this video card and it ran fine. I also ran a memtest it was ok.

Comment: @Fofole well in that case send it in! The 7850 isn't exactly a low-power card so I don't think your PSU is at fault (BTW I have the same one and I love it).